# How should modals/popups be managed in an Angular application?

Tags: angular

How should modals/popups be managed in an Angular application?

I was thinking of putting components to contain modals and notifications in the project root component. Then I could use a service to manage the state of the all the components.

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-notification-overlay></app-notification-overlay>
<app-modal></app-modal>
<app-notification-example></app-notification-example>
... etc
```

Service:

```
PostModalActive: Observable<boolean>;
SubscriptionNotificationActive: Observable<boolean>;
TestNotificationActive: Observable<boolean>;
```

Then in these modal/notification components inject this service to share state.

**style.css**

```
app-notification-a {
  bottom: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  ...
}

app-modal-b {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You could look at Angular Material’s dialog for an example.  I believe they do something similar to what you have setup.

Comment: Have you checked with [angular material dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

Comment: @Pankaj Prakash it doesn't included anything for services or component state, it's not similar

Comment: The link guides you to create modal dialog box. It does not adds any of your business logic. If you want to add/show/pass services to the modal popup you can achieve that.